# illegal offset string in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, warnings

I installed a template that I didn't write.

Everything is OK, just I have about 8 errors in one page that I bring it in below:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'store_name' in
>   F:\xamp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\tf\single-product.php on
>   line 99

the other errors are exactly the same just in different lines.

```
enter code here
 <!--details-->
    <div class="content_item">
               <!-- the first below Line is 99 -->
      <div class="Slogan"><span><?php echo $seller_details['store_name']; ?>  
    </span></div>

  <div class="info-counter">
     <span class="info-timerLabel"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i>Purchase 
        deadline</span>

<div id="retroclockbox_sm1"></div>
    <p><span>second</span> <span>minute</span> <span>hour</span> 
  <span>day</span></p>
</div>

    <script src="<?php 
          bloginfo('template_url');>/js/jquery.flipcountdown.js">
       </script>
                            <!-- Flip Count Down -->
```

I have read some the same problem in stack. But they couldn't help.

Comment: well seems you are trying to use string as an array. `var_dump($seller_details)` to check what you have here

Comment: i forgot to mention i am beginner in wordpress and i am not familiar with php

Comment: `var_dump ` your variable `$seller_details` and check if it has a key with name of `store_name`.

Comment: it returns string 
i think the problem has come from the template.
i will call to it's backup

Comment: thank u for comments